# Python module with requirements from test repo

Tags: python, python-packaging

For some internal development I created a package that depends on another package that is currently under development.
I would like to add in my setup.py requirement for the test version of that package, that is:

```
setuptools.setup(
...
install_requires=[...], #from pypi
??install_requires_dev??=[...], #from pypi-test
```

)

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

in your setup.py script your going to want to set that package as an external dependancy

```
#module/setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
   name='foo',
   version='1.0',
   description='A useful module',
   author='Man Foo',
   author_email='foomail@foo.com',
   packages=['foo'],  #same as name
   install_requires=['bar', 'greek'], #external packages as dependencies
)
```

replace bar or greek with your module name, this runs `pip3 install module` every time so if you update the external package this module will reinstall the package automatically when you run the module.

also if your scripts are in a scripts folder inside the module you will have to add a scripts attribute so your code would look more like this.

```
#module/setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
   name='foo',
   version='1.0',
   description='A useful module',
   author='Man Foo',
   author_email='foomail@foo.com',
   packages=['foo'],  #same as name
   install_requires=['bar', 'greek'], #external packages as dependencies
   scripts=[scripts/script1, scripts/script2]
)
```

Comment: but 'bar' and 'greek' will be installed from pypi, while I would like 'greek' tro be installed from test-pypi